# Merge info from two xml files in one, using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

File a.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TABLE NAME="pivot.cs">
   <DATA RECORDS="2">
      <RECORD ID="1">
         <INTERNALID>5510</INTERNALID>
         <SOMED>1</SOMED>
         <PEMED>1</PEMED>
         <CODAL>PLACEHOLD</CODAL>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="2">
         <INTERNALID>5511</INTERNALID>
         <SOMED>1</SOMED>
         <PEMED>1</PEMED>
         <CODAL>PLACEHOLD</CODAL>
      </RECORD>
      <INTERNALID>5537</INTERNALID>
      <SOMED>1</SOMED>
      <PEMED>1</PEMED>
      <CODAL>PLACEHOLD</CODAL>
   </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

file b.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TABLE NAME="ALT.CS">
   <DATA RECORDS="20">
      <RECORD ID="53">
         <RECNO>5510</RECNO>
         <TOBEEXTRACTED>TIM</TOBEEXTRACTED>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="53">
         <RECNO>5510</RECNO>
         <TOBEEXTRACTED>KLM</TOBEEXTRACTED>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="54">
         <RECNO>5510</RECNO>
         <TOBEEXTRACTED>KAB</TOBEEXTRACTED>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="55">
         <RECNO>5511</RECNO>
         <TOBEEXTRACTED>BUS WEE</TOBEEXTRACTED>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="59">
         <RECNO>5512</RECNO>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="60">
         <RECNO>5513</RECNO>
         </RECORD>
         <RECORD ID="5511">
            <RECNO>5598</RECNO>
            <TOBEEXTRACTED>FBV</TOBEEXTRACTED>
         </RECORD>
      </RECORD>
   </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

and output file should be, the file a.xml, but with the TOBEEXTRACTED element text appended into [], if matched one or two times:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TABLE NAME="pivot.cs">
   <DATA RECORDS="2">
      <RECORD ID="1">
         <INTERNALID>5510</INTERNALID>
         <SOMED>1</SOMED>
         <PEMED>1</PEMED>
         <CODAL>PLACEHOLD</CODAL>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="2">
         <INTERNALID>5511</INTERNALID>
         <SOMED>1</SOMED>
         <PEMED>1</PEMED>
         <CODAL>PLACEHOLD [BUS WEE]</CODAL>
      </RECORD>
      <INTERNALID>5537</INTERNALID>
      <SOMED>1</SOMED>
      <PEMED>1</PEMED>
      <CODAL>PLACEHOLD</CODAL>
   </DATA>
</TABLE>
```

Also, it would be of much help, if we could have a txt file as output, that would have the following info:
from file a.xml,

```
INTERNALID: 5511 (and all the rest in a normal xml file) was matched.
INTERNALID: 5510 was matched more than two times, so no join took place.
INTERNALID: 5537 did not match
RECNO 5512 did not have a TOBEEXTRACTED element.
```

Comment: Can you at least edit the input and wanted output samples to show examples of the cases you are interested in (elements matched, not matched, matched more than two times, matched without `TOBEEXTRACTED` element?

Comment: Also consider to show your attempt to solving this with XSLT 2.0, you can solve the cross-reference easy enough with a key `<xsl:key name="ref" match="DATA/RECORD[TOBEEXTRACTED]" use="RECNO"/>` and then match `<xsl:template match="DATA/RECORD[key('ref', INTERNALID, doc('fileb.xml')]/CODAL"><xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' [', key('ref', ../INTERNALID, doc('fileb.xml'))/TOBEEXTRACTED, ']')"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`

Comment: hope it is more clear now, thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a key as suggested in a comment you can reference and match elements as follows:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="doc2">
        <TABLE NAME="ALT.CS">
   <DATA RECORDS="20">
      <RECORD ID="53">
         <RECNO>5510</RECNO>
         <TOBEEXTRACTED>TIM</TOBEEXTRACTED>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="53">
         <RECNO>5510</RECNO>
         <TOBEEXTRACTED>KLM</TOBEEXTRACTED>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="54">
         <RECNO>5510</RECNO>
         <TOBEEXTRACTED>KAB</TOBEEXTRACTED>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="55">
         <RECNO>5511</RECNO>
         <TOBEEXTRACTED>BUS WEE</TOBEEXTRACTED>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="59">
         <RECNO>5512</RECNO>
      </RECORD>
      <RECORD ID="60">
         <RECNO>5513</RECNO>
         </RECORD>
         <RECORD ID="5511">
            <RECNO>5598</RECNO>
            <TOBEEXTRACTED>FBV</TOBEEXTRACTED>
         </RECORD>

   </DATA>
</TABLE>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:key name="ref" match="DATA/RECORD[TOBEEXTRACTED]" use="RECNO"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DATA/RECORD[key('ref', INTERNALID, $doc2)]/CODAL">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node(), key('ref', ../INTERNALID, $doc2)/TOBEEXTRACTED"/>  
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DATA/RECORD[not(key('ref', INTERNALID, $doc2))]"/>

    <xsl:template match="TOBEEXTRACTED">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(' [', ., ']')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

That gives the output you have posted at http://xsltransform.net/a9Giwy. There I have used an `xsl:param name="doc2"` with inline contents but you can of course use `<xsl:param name="doc2" select="doc('fileb.xml')"/>` instead.

As in an edit the question was additionally tagged as [xslt-3.0](/questions/tagged/xslt-3.0) I have also tried to implement it using the `xsl:merge` instruction of that version:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="doc2-uri" as="xs:string" select="'test201705120102.xml'"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="TABLE/DATA">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:merge>
                <xsl:merge-source name="internal" select="RECORD" >
                    <xsl:merge-key select="INTERNALID"/>
                </xsl:merge-source>
                <xsl:merge-source name="recno" select="doc($doc2-uri)//RECORD">
                    <xsl:merge-key select="RECNO"/>
                </xsl:merge-source>
                <xsl:merge-action>
                    <xsl:if test="current-merge-group('internal') and current-merge-group('recno')">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="@*, * except CODAL"/>
                            <CODAL>
                                <xsl:value-of select="CODAL, current-merge-group('recno')/TOBEEXTRACTED/('[' || . || ']')"/>
                            </CODAL>
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:merge-action>
            </xsl:merge>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Actually I would like all changes to be overwritten to the original XML, by mistake, in the output file, I have only included the changed records, and last, how I could alter the above examples, in order, to get a report of what was changed, and what was not?

Comment: I am sure XSLT is a programming language and can be used to report the details but your question has not even made it clear whether and where you want that info in the result sample you have shown and whether you want it to be included in a second result file, so I focused on answering the part that seemed to have a clear requirement description. If you edit your question and explain and show where/how you want the information then I am sure we can help with the code.

Comment: have redescribed my question, with the hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 0):

This kind of merging can often be accomplished using xsl:for-each-group:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$doc1//REC, $doc2//REC" group-by="RECNO">
  ...
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

in the body, current-group() holds the records from both files with the required key. You can separate them out with, for example

```
<xsl:variable name="doc1rec" select="current-group()[(/) is $doc1]"/>
<xsl:variable name="doc2rec" select="current-group()[(/) is $doc2]"/>
```

and then the remaining processing should be straightforward if you understand the logic (which I don't).